# In Mongo shell typing any string and press enter, the string gets duplicated

Tags: mongodb

I am facing very unusual issue in Mongo shell.

**Issue**: Wherever I try to query any string in mongo shell, the query string gets repeated (or duplicated) after pressing enter instead what i type.

For example: if i type **show dbs** and press enter, i get the output but if i check the command which i typed, it gets repeated(or duplicated)

```
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs
show dbs
admin                     0.000GB
config                    0.000GB
local                     0.327GB
```

Any idea why its happening or how to fix it?

Please help

Comment: which version of shell and server?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.0.10

Comment: root@0c61604e935f:/# /usr/bin/mongo -version
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
git version: c389e7f69f637f7a1ac3cc9fae843b635f20b766
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distmod: ubuntu1604
    distarch: x86_64
root@0c61604e935f:/#

Comment: I would suspect an incorrect terminal setting, or something in the .mongorc.js

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with Old version of SecureCRT (via which i used login to MongoDB), switched to MobaXterm and all fine now!